# Using File manager with Sharepoint Online

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to connect to SharePoint Online to browse the folder on SharePoint and get the image file to import into sql table. Unable to get to it through File Manager - the path shows as invalid (if I browse through SharePoint and enter my u/p - path is accessible and valid)

I had setup a code asking for user's password (username I get automatically) and it seems to connect to SharePoint online, however when I type the path in the browser - get invalid path error.

Calling this code to pass u/p (behind the scenes):

```html
protected void ConnectShrpt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String DocLibName = "Documents";
        If ((HiddenPassw.Value != "") && (HiddenUserEmail.Value !=""))
        {
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(FolderImage);              
                SharePointOnlineCredentials cred = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(HiddenUserEmail.Value, ConvertToSecureString(HiddenPassw.Value));
                clientContext.Credentials = cred;
                List list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(DocLibName);              
                clientContext.Load(list.RootFolder);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();  
            }
        }
​
```

I don't get any error messages for the code above. Once I get to the browser - using asp:FileUpload - that's when I get the error that path doesn't exist. If I manually go in the same browser to the same location and enter u/p - then I can use the same FileUpload and browse to that location. I need my code to connect to the SharePoint Online automatically.
P.S. FolderImage is the SharePoint site' url.

Update! While I got no errors in the developer environment, once I deployed it to the SharePoint Server IIS - getting an error on the code that I enclosed above..

```html
[IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected packet format.]
   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +420
   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +287
   System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +357
   System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) +203
   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult) +827
   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) +357
   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) +20
   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) +77
   System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result) +1135
   System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) +60
   System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) +105
   System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async) +484

[WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +1518
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.SharePointOnlineAuthenticationProvider.GetIdcrlHeader(Uri url, Boolean alwaysThrowOnFailure, EventHandler`1 executingWebRequest) +1129
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Idcrl.SharePointOnlineAuthenticationProvider.GetAuthenticationCookie(Uri url, String username, SecureString password, Boolean alwaysThrowOnFailure, EventHandler`1 executingWebRequest) +122
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials.GetAuthenticationCookie(Uri url, Boolean refresh, Boolean alwaysThrowOnFailure) +402
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.SetupRequestCredential(ClientRuntimeContext context, HttpWebRequest request) +743
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SPWebRequestExecutor.GetRequestStream() +68
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetFormDigestInfoPrivate() +635
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.EnsureFormDigest() +104
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery() +1397
   AIM_Central._Default.ConnectShrpt_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in Default.aspx.cs:4139
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +129
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +141
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4949
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the data of the "**FolderImage**" variable.

To pass the ClientContext method, you need pass the site url.

```
string webUrl = "https://tenant-name.sharepoint.com/sites/test/";
ClientContext clientContext  = new ClientContext(webUrl)
```

Comment: Debug the code and check which line of code throw the exception.

Comment: I had mentioned before that I get no errors on this code. It just doesn't achieve what I need - doesn't unblock the connection to the path on the SharePoint.